# Dataset won't update image to database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

I'm trying to insert an image into a SQL Server database, it get into the dataset but when the save method is called, SQL Server doesn't change.

```
public void AddImage(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1, List<Movie> movieList)
{
    byte[] movieCover = null;
    FileStream movieStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader movieReader = new BinaryReader(movieStream);
    movieCover = movieReader.ReadBytes((int)movieStream.Length);
    var Starwars = new object[2];
    Starwars[0] = "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace";
    Starwars[1] = "1999";
    var found = _movieSet.Tables["Movie"].Rows.Find(Starwars);

    if (found != null)
    {
        found.SetField("Cover", movieCover);
        var movieListFound = movieList.Find(x => x.Name == Starwars[0]);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Movie Not Found");
}
```

The save method

```
 public void Save()
 {
     var movieConnection = new SqlConnection();
     try
     {
         movieConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.moviesConnectionString);
         movieConnection.Open();
         _movieAdapter.Update(_movieSet, "Movie");
         movieConnection.Close();                
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
          movieConnection.Dispose();
      }
 }
```

Adding new rows works but any sort of change to the actual data set is not updated when the save method is called, not just image but if I change the table data with data visualizer in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Yet again I answer my own question a day later, wish I got better responses but I suppose my information must not be the best or something.

I needed to call the Save() method during the Addimage method.

```
public void AddImage(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1, List<Movie> movieList)
{
     byte[] movieCover = null;
     FileStream movieStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     BinaryReader movieReader = new BinaryReader(movieStream);
     movieCover = movieReader.ReadBytes((int)movieStream.Length);
     var Starwars = new object[2];
     Starwars[0] = "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace";
     Starwars[1] = 1999;
     var found = MovieTable().Rows.Find(Starwars);
     if (found != null)
     {
         found["Cover"] = movieCover;
         var movieListFound = movieList.Find(x => x.Name == Starwars[0]);
     }
     else
         MessageBox.Show("Movie Not Found");
     Save();
```

}